# boost IPC using socket stream and boost::asio::io_service

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, ipc

I have an IPC issue and i need to use `boost::asio::io_service` to do so. 
The idea is to open a pipe connection between 2 threads where thread#1 notifies thread#2, and thread#2 uses `boost::asio::io_service` and wake up when thread#1 send a message.

I saw example of a binding 2 stream sockets together using connect_pair so writing to one end is readable on the other end. I will refer it as `readfd` and `writefd`.

I want to assign `writefd` to thread#1 and `readfd` to thread#2. Then thread#2 should run the `io_service` and wait for event.

Writing to `writefd` should invoke this event that will cause thread 2 to wake up.

But up until now i could not figure how to do it.

here is sort of a main idea of what I am trying to do:

```
 boost::asio::io_service io;
 boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket readfd (io);
 boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket writefd (io);
 boost::asio::local::connect_pair( readfd, writefd );

 //allocate writefd to thread 1
 ....

 //wait for read event - << how to do it? 

 io.run()
```

I thought I might use:

```
boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor
//or 
//open and bind but i could not understand how to do so
```

Comment: "I have an IPC issue and i need to use boost::asio::io_service to do so" - This always sends my eyebrows in a twist. What on earth causes these unlikely constraints?

Comment: And why is that if i may ask? 
Do you have a better solution?

Comment: I might. If the goal was clear. Do the threads live in one process always? what's the nature of the messages/events/packets?